# Any way to upgrade from 9.04 to 10.10 with no CD drive?

Tags: 10.10, usb-drive, 9.04, updates, cd-drive

My CD drive is broken and i am still on 9.4 and i want to update or clean install straight to 10.10. I do not care how I upgrade as long as i do not havew to use a CD drive or install the previous updates. I would also like to know if i can use a USB drive to install desktop edition? Thank You.

Comment: Why not use the update manager?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can upgrade and install Ubuntu by using a [USB stick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick). Do note that you cannot upgrade from 9.04 to 10.10 directly, you can move from 9.04 to 9.10 to 10.04 to 10.10 though.

That can take a long time so you'll probably save a bunch of time by backing up your data and reinstalling.

Comment: Just download an ISO image of Ubuntu 10.10 from ubuntu.com and use Startup Disk Creator (System > Administration > Startup Disk Creator) to "burn" it to your USB flash drive. If you install it to the same disk keeping existing partition structure, you might even save data in your home directory. But as always - backup all your important data before doing this! :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for answering or looking. i have found the answer, as you do when you install net-book edition you install it using a USB stick. here is the link provided. http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/download

Comment: That's what Jorge said ;)